# Docker build image fails - No such file or directory

Tags: .net, linux, docker, dockerfile, containers

I created a .Net Core app in Visual Sutdio 2019 and added docker support so it automatically generates the file but when I build the docker image the output says:

```
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.typescript.msbuild/3.9.5/tools/Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(551,5): 
error MSB6003: The specified task executable "node" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception 
(2): No such file or directory [/src/CyberEvalNextGen.csproj]
```

I assume there is an issue with COPY but I am not sure.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CyberEvalNextGen.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./CyberEvalNextGen.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "CyberEvalNextGen.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CyberEvalNextGen.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CyberEvalNextGen.dll"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  The error is a bit misleading because it has your .csproj listed at the end, but this is the key part:

```
The specified task executable "node" could not be run.
```

It is actually looking to run the command "node" and it cannot find the executable.  To resolve this, I added Node.js just prior to my build step.

```
...
WORKDIR "/src/."
#Installing Node.js in build container
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nodejs                   
RUN dotnet build "CyberEvalNextGen.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
...
```

This is using Linux containers, but I believe you can do something similar with PowerShell in Windows containers.